# Ajax TabContainer Rendering Problem

Tags: ajax, rendering, tabcontainer

I'm using Ajax TabContainer with a number of tabs,and IE as browser.
On one of the tabs, which is created and added dinamically, I'm showing a number of charts.
Sometimes some of the charts are missing, and after changing tab or selecting the area by mouse, the chart apears.

This problem exists only in production environment, in other words, in development environment there is no problem.

Thanks very much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the issue, even though in a tricky way.
I forced the tabContainer to redraw after the page is loaded:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var tabIndex = $find("<%=TabContainer1.ClientID%>").get_activeTabIndex() ; 
    $find("<%=TabContainer1.ClientID%>").set_activeTabIndex(tabIndex);} 
, 4000)
```

It does nothing but activating the tab which is already active.

However, I'm wondering if there is any better resolution.